# access child model in parent validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model that has a child model

```
class Student
  has_many :student_records, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_records, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['record'].blank? }

  # Now I would like to access the child model here during creating new records, for validation

  validate :sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred

  def sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred
    @sum = 0
    student_records.each do |sr|
      @sum += sr.record
    end
  end
  if @sum > 100
    errors.add(:base, :sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred)
  end
end

class StudentRecord
  belongs_to :student
end
```

The problem is student_records.each does not work because student_records is empty but i can see it in the params.What's going on?

Here is a part of the students controller

```
Class StudentsController
  def new  
    @st = Student.new
    @st.student_records.build
  end

  def create
    @student = Studnet.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
      flash[:success] = t('student_saved')
      redirect_to students_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:full_name, .......,
                                    student_records_attributes:
                                      [:id, :record, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Comment: First of all correct typo **belongs_to :student**

Comment: Yes, but the validation is not working

Comment: It works during editing, but not for new records

Comment: Add your `StudentsController`

Comment: Can you attach code for: How you are building student_records while creating Student

Comment: Maybe it'll work if You correct another typo here: `@student = Studnet.new(student_params)`

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the `if...end` outside the validation method. You don't have to use instance variable either, local variable will do the work.

Try this:

```
def sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred
  sum = 0
  student_records.each do |sr|
    sum += sr.record
  end

  errors.add(:base, :sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred) if sum > 100
end
```

Comment: Same result. Thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,
change your validate source like this:

```
def sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred
    sum = 0
      self.student_records.each do |sr|
        sum += sr.record
      end 
   if sum > 100
     errors.add(:base, :sum_of_records_has_to_be_less_than_hundred)
   end
 end
```